# What are the different types of 'double' in Swift?

Tags: swift, variables, double

In swift, there are different variable types such as `Int`, `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32` and `Int64` are examples, of this. I noticed the `Double`, `double2`, `double3` and `double4` types. What do each of these do? It would be useful if there are better ones to use in my program than others.

Comment: @Carpsen90 Please elaborate. Which takes more memory, double, 2, 3, or 4? And how many bits?

Comment: @Carpsen90 there definitely is. Im on Xcode right now and its here.

Comment: double2/3/4 are [simd structures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/simd_structures) for vectorized calculations, essentially structs containing 2/3/4 double values.

Comment: @Carpsen90 how can I include code? I just started typing Double and there they are, double 2 3 and 4. In lowercase rather than uppercase.

Comment: @Carpsen90 How should I edit it? What? I just want to know how much double 2 3 and 4 take up???

Comment: @Carpsen90 I HAVE NOT IMPORTED SIMD? I DO NOT KNOW WHAT THAT IS

Comment: Why is everyone shitting so hard on OP? It's a totally valid question. Even I didn't know the answer, until Martin's comment.

Comment: @Alexander thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

`double2`, `double3` and `double4` are not types defined in Swift Standard Library.

They are defined in simd framework, and representing vector types with 2, 3 or 4 `Double` elements.

[double2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/double2), [double3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/double3), [double4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/double4)

---

Simple usage:

```
import simd

let v1 = double2(1.0, 2.0)
let v2 = double2(3.0, 4.0)

let v3 = v1+v2
print(v3) //->double2(4.0, 6.0)
```

There are many other functionalities in simd framework. Please explore [`simd` framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd) pages.

Comment: Ok, but how many bits? How much memory, or other uses for them

Comment: @user10470035, they are vector types. Not simple floating point number types. As I wrote in my answer, they represent 2, 3 or 4 `Double`s. They are intended to utilize SIMD functionalities of CPUs. Use cases to tell you depends on how much you know about vector and matrix processing.